# How to display unordered list as inline but with each item on a seperate line using CSS? Pic example

Tags: css, html-lists

Hi I'm not sure how to do this without adding extra HTML elements. Its probably easiest to view the following image which I have made to describe what I would like to accomplish:

http://i43.tinypic.com/2qdokr8.jpg

As you should be able to see on the image I want to style my unordered lists with a background or borders that only extends as far as the text in each li. However by default the li is 100% the width of the containing element. I can do it with display:inline or display:inline-block however then each li doesn't start on a separate line, which is no good.

I understand I could simply add a span element inside the li and display that inline with my styles which would accomplish what I want to do. But I don't want to have to manually add span elements in wordpress each time I create a list.

Am I missing a simple trick here that could be used to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clear:left;` property here Like this:

```
li{
    background:red;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/KebB3/

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. I should have mentioned I tried that too which, works fine however if you have a paragraph after the list it wraps around the list and looks a complete mess :( see... http://jsfiddle.net/KebB3/6/

Comment: @user1027682; just give clear:both in your p like this p{clear:both}

Comment: Seems like I've found the answer with the help of the above poster (sandeep).

I had tried floating and clearing each li which worked but the following paragraphs etc would wrap around the floated items looking messy.

It seems adding 'overflow:auto' to the ul overcomes this issue :D example: http://jsfiddle.net/KebB3/7/

Thanks for the replies... I thought there had to be a css only way to do this without adding extra elements.

Comment: @ sandeep; Yes I realise I could have cleared the float with the p but I didn't want to clear floats with all my paragraphs as then I can't wrap the text around floated images, or other items which I do quite a bit. Also didn't want to have to add a manual empty clearfloat div as that is extra code too. Thanks for your help